# How to create GUI in Android instead of using XML?

Tags: java, android, xml, user-interface

I don't like to manage `XML` and `Java` together, can I create same GUI using `Java` language?
How can I do that, can you tell me code for simple `Button`?
I will appreciate the proper answer.

Answer (score 15):

Yes, you can.

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
     protected void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
         super.onCreate(icicle);

         final Button button = new Button(this);
         button.setText("Press me!");
         setContentView(button);

         button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             public void onClick(View v) {
                 // Perform action on click
             }
         });
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 8):

> Can I create same GUI using Java language?

Yes you can create GUI in `Java` code also as answered by **@dtmilano** but in general it's not a good practice for `Android` applications. Its easy in case of a small application but if you are going to develop an application for End User than your must have to create GUI using XML files. Its also useful when you want to develop application targeted for multiple devices with different-different display size and different-different languages.

The best practice is that try to avoid creating GUI using `Java` and instead use `XML` as much you can.

Comment: Why is creating UI with Java a bad practice? What if I want to change the position of TextViews, images or other UI objects without using GL?

Comment: some developers simply prefer to write Java code than to use layout tools and XML, regardless of the advantages offered by the latter approaches

Comment: https://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Creating_an_Android_User_Interface_in_Java_Code

Answer (score 3):

I found this article useful maybe It's good for you too
[Creating an Android User Inteface in java Code](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Creating_an_Android_User_Interface_in_Java_Code)

first you need to create an object for your layout like this

```
RelativeLayout myLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);
```

then create your for example button like this

```
Button myButton = new Button(this);
```

then the Button view needs to be added as a child to the RelativeLayout view which, in turn, is displayed via a call to the setContentView() method of the activity instance

```
myLayout.addView(myButton);
setContentView(myLayout);
```

Once launched, the visible result will be a button containing no text appearing in the top left hand corner of the RelativeLayout view.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely you can design your Android UI using java.
Here is a little example for create a Button.

Follow these steps

1. import a layout package(here i've import android.widget.RelativeLayout)
2. import Button package
3. Create a layout object
4. Create a button object
5. Add button to layout
6. Set Content View

Here is the code

```
package com.example.vmbck.app3;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.Button;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //create layout
    RelativeLayout myLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);
    //set background color of the layout to Green
    myLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);

    //create button
    Button myButton = new Button(this);
    //set button's background color to red
    myButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
    //set button's text to Click Me
    myButton.setText("Click Me");

    //add button to layout
    myLayout.addView(myButton);
    //View the content
    setContentView(myLayout);
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are using Eclipse, you can go to folder res/layout from your project where you will find the file main.xml
Right click this file and choose Open with/Android layout editor
There you will see a graphical tool that will generate all that is needed to be included in the main.xml file

Comment: Ya didn't answer the question at all.