# dialog - The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first

Tags: java, android

After a check demanding the user to switch on internet services and I try to click on a button my app crashes with the error message

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
```

On this line it crashes, I have tried doing this but not resolved absolutely

```
if(alert.getContext() != null){
            alert.show();
        }
```

This is the complete code

```
else if (id == R.id.xyz) {

            //startActivity(borrowIntent);
            AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            alert.setTitle("xyz");
            input.setFilters(new InputFilter[] {
                    // Maximum 2 characters.
                    new InputFilter.LengthFilter(6),
                    // Digits only.
                    DigitsKeyListener.getInstance(), 
                });
            // Digits only & use numeric soft-keyboard.
            input.setKeyListener(DigitsKeyListener.getInstance());
            input.setHint("xyz");
            alert.setView(input);
            alert.setPositiveButton("Borrow", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                if(input.getText().length() == 0)
                {
                    input.setError("xyz is required !");
                }
                else
                {

                   if(isNetworkAvailable())
                      {
                         xyz( input.getText().toString());

                      }else{

                            //setContentView(R.layout.main);

                            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                                    MainActivity.this);
                              builder.setCancelable(false);
                              builder.setTitle("xyz");
                              builder.setMessage("Please enable wifi services");
                              builder.setInverseBackgroundForced(true);
                              builder.setPositiveButton("Ok",
                                      new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                          @Override
                                          public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                                  int which) {

                                              startActivityForResult(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS), 0);
                                              dialog.dismiss();


                                          }
                                      });
                              AlertDialog alerts = builder.create();
                              alerts.show();
                           }//end of block

                        }
              }
            });
            alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
              public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                // Canceled.
              }
            });
            if(alert.getContext() != null){
            alert.show(); //crashes at this line
            }
        }
```

Please what am I missing?

Comment: Can you paste activity or fragment code in which you are using that dialog

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The problem is on this line:
`alert.setView(input);`
You added `input` `View` that have already `parent`.
Create new `input` instance.

Comment: I need only an input instance of type Edittext declared at class level

Comment: [Generating EditText programatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12985825/generating-edit-text-programatically-in-android)

Comment: but you have to place a check if the view is null or not null

Answer (score 19):

according to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28071349/the-specified-child-already-has-a-parent-you-must-call-removeview-on-the-chil), add this check to remove input from it's parent and readd it:

```
if(input.getParent()!=null)
        ((ViewGroup)input.getParent()).removeView(input); // <- fix
    alert.addView(input);
```

Answer (score 3):

Put following line

```
 final AlertDialog alertd = alert.create();
```

After

```
 AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
```

Comment: the input is actually a textfield. so on removing the user will have field to input data

Comment: Dialog is in fragment or in activity

Comment: input is a reference to Edittext

Comment: I have to modify my code. Because I cant find the code

Comment: So where will I now use this handle alerd

Answer (score 1):

Following situation can also happen (happened to me):

Sometimes when you use a listview you initialize it with an adapter, which belongs to a certain layout. Now lets say the root view of this layout file is a `<LinearLayout>` with the id "root_view".

If you register now for a context menu in your activity and create an `AlerdDialog.Builder` which appears after choosing a certain menu element and initialize it with a layout file, which also has a root element with an id called "root_view" where all elements which belong to your `AlertDialog` are children of it, then those elements "will not be found". You will not be able to access those elements with `findViewById`, instead you can only access the elements from the `<LinearLayout>` of your list view and you get the same error message at the line where you call `builder.show()` (or in the case here `alert.show()`).

So generally it is a good idea to name the ids of your elements in the layout files uniquely, for your project.

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to call `create()` on the `AlertDialog.Builder`. When you call `show()` without calling the `create()` method, the `AlertDialog` instance gets created. This worked the first time but then subsequent clicks got the `IllegalStateException`. As I was calling `show()` inside of my `onClickListener`, it was going to create a new `AlertDialog` instance every time button was clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line at start

```
View dialog_view= getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialog_view, null);
TextInputEditText input = dialog_view.findViewById(R.id.input);
```

before

```
AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
```

that way a new instance of input is created and avoid the problem