# how is the correct desing pattern to hide/show EditText in Android?

Tags: android, android-edittext, material-design

I have developed an Health App in Android, and i have an Activity where the first question is a Yes/No answer (i make with 2 checkboxes), depending the Yes/No answer the activity shows diferents `EditText` to complete. I really know how to hide `EditText` and how to show when the user click the checkboxes, but the question is if exist a correct design pattern to do this? i read the [Material Desing web](https://material.google.com/) , but i didnt find nothing about this. It is correct way to do? Or i must enable/disable the `EditTexts`.

Comment: `android:visibility="invisible"` and `visible` when needed. Can also set it programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to set a few EditText's, your way is right.

**OPTION A**

Imagine that "foo()" returns which is the EditText that you have to show.

In your layout:

```
<EditText
 android:id="@+id/edit1"
 android:visibility="GONE"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<EditText
 android:id="@+id/edit2"
 android:visibility="GONE"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

....
```

Now, in your code:

```
...
switch(foo()){
  case 1: //You have to show the first EditText
    EditText edit1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit1);
    edit1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    break;
  case 2: //You have to show the second EditText
    EditText edit2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit2);
    edit2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    break;
  ....
 }
```

**OPTION B**

Another choice would be adding the EditText programatically, something like:

```
EditText editText = new EditText(context); // Pass it an Activity or   Context
editText.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(..., ...)); // Pass two args; must be LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, or an integer pixel value.
myLayout.addView(editText);
```

In this case, you dont need to add the EditText's in the layout file, you are going to add it dynamically only if you need it!

[Generating Edit Text Programatically in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12985825/generating-edit-text-programatically-in-android)

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks, maybe my question is a litlee confused, I already know how to do that. The question is if this method is correct in in desing of android.

Comment: As I said in my answer if you only are going to have a couple of EditText's, it is right. But if you want to control a more specific situation, check the option B that is more efficent.